# Retaining search criteria in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery DataTables. I am working on an existing project that uses datatables. On one such screen when a value is entered in the search textbox, filtering takes place globally as well as on columns. Currently in my application every time I hit this screen Search textbox appears blank. This is not the expected behavior. I want to retain the search text so that the next time I visit this screen, I dont have to type the search criteria again. Is there a specific property of a DataTable which should be set in order to reset the search text?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DataTables' state saving option: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/state_save.html ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!This helped. But I have a few more questions. I want to convert the search textbox of the datatable into a combo box such that as the user begins typing, it displays 10 most recent items/strings that were searched. How can this be implemented in datatables? Also is predictive search possible in this case?